# df.head() sometimes doesn't work in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner in Python and the Pandas library, and I'm rather confused by some basic functionality of DataFrame. I've got a pandas DataFrame as below:

```
>>>df.head()  
              X  Y       unixtime
0  652f5e69fcb3  1  1346689910622
1        400292  1  1346614723542
2  1c9d02e4f14e  1  1346862070161
3        610449  1  1346806384518
4        207664  1  1346723370096
```

However, after I performed some function:

```
def unixTodate(unix):
  day = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  return day

df['day'] = df['unixtime'].apply(unixTodate)
```

I could no longer make use of the df.head() function:

```
>>>df.head()  

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 190648 to 626582
Data columns:
X              5  non-null values
Y              5  non-null values
unixtime       5  non-null values
day            5  non-null values
dtypes: int64(3), object(5)
```

I can't see why this is happening. Am I doing something wrong here? Any pointer is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`df.head(n)` returns a `DataFrame` holding the first n rows of df.
Now to display a `DataFrame` pandas checks by default the width of the terminal, if this is too small to display the `DataFrame` a summary view will be shown. Which is what you get in the second case.

Could you increase the size of your terminal, or disable autodetect on the columns by `pd.set_printoptions(max_columns=10)`?

Comment: Thanks Wouter - it works now. But my second data frame is actually one column wider than my first one, so I'm a bit surprised that it couldn't be displayed. Is there any documentation you could point me to?

Comment: there is not much ... http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#console-output-formatting

Comment: btw what to you get for pd.util.terminal.get_terminal_size()? This should be (terminal_width, terminal_height). If pandas can not autodetect it (80, 25) is returned by default.

Comment: I see. Thanks. My terminal size is (112, 24).

Comment: Seems big enough to display df.head() in both cases?

Comment: Indeed. The fact is the data frame above is just for demonstration - my actual data frame is slightly bigger - 7 columns to start with, then another column is added. It displayed df.head() fine with the 7 columns, but only gave a summary of the 8-column data frame, and refused to display even the original 7-column data frame since then. I found it rather confusing..

Comment: But yeah, after adjusting the terminal size manually, df.head() works.

Comment: Just FYI, `pandas.set_printoptions` is now deprecated. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#working-with-package-options The max columns can be changed with `pandas.set_option`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code segment:

```
from IPython.display import display
display(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DataFrame.head(n=5)
```

Return the first n rows.

This function returns the first n rows for the object based on position. It is useful for quickly testing if your object has the right type of data in it.

Parameters:

```
n : int, default 5
```

Number of rows to select.

Returns:

```
obj_head : type of caller
```

The first n rows of the caller object.