# Pandas df.head() Error

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm having a basic problem with df.head(). When the function is executed, it usually displays a nice HTML formatted table of the top 5 values, but now it only appears to slice the dataframe and outputs like below:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 9 columns):
survived    5  non-null values
pclass      5  non-null values
name        5  non-null values
sex         5  non-null values
age         5  non-null values
sibsp       5  non-null values
parch       5  non-null values
fare        5  non-null values
embarked    5  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), int64(4), object(3)
```

After looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085709/df-head-sometimes-doesnt-work-in-pandas-python) I tried

```
pd.util.terminal.get_terminal_size()
```

and received the expected output (80, 25). Manually setting the print options  with

```
pd.set_printoptions(max_columns=10)
```

Yields the same sliced dataframe results like above.

This was confirmed after diving into the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#console-output-formatting) and using the

```
get_option("display.max_rows")
get_option("display.max_columns")
```

and getting the correct default 60 rows and 10 columns.

I've never had a problem with df.head() before but now its an issue in all of my IPython Notebooks.

I'm running pandas 0.11.0 and IPython 0.13.2 in google chrome.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, y-p has put together [a pull-request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3657) to correct this behaviour, if you'd like to test it. I'm pretty sure we'll be able to get this 11.1 (out in a few days).

Comment: @AndyHayden Great, I'll test it first thing tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas 11.0, I think the *minimum* of `display.height` and `max_rows` (and `display.width` and max_columns`) is used, so you need to manually change that too.

*I don't like this, I posted this [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3541) about it previously.*

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following to display the top 10 items

```
from IPython.display import HTML 
HTML(users.head(10).to_html())
```

I think pandas 11.0 head function is totally unintuitive and should
simply have remained as head() and you get your html.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I'll look into it. I believe that the pandas developers have fixed this issue and made it more intuitive in pandas 11.1