# Python equivalent of R's head and tail function

Tags: python, r, view, pandas

I want to preview a Pandas dataframe.  I would use head(mymatrix) in R, but I do not know how to do this in Pandas Python.

When I type

df.head(10) I get...

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 14 columns):
#Book_Date            10  non-null values
Item_Qty              10  non-null values
Item_id               10  non-null values
Location_id           10  non-null values
MFG_Discount          10  non-null values
Sale_Revenue          10  non-null values
Sales_Flg             10  non-null values
Sell_Unit_Cost        5  non-null values
Store_Discount        10  non-null values
Transaction_Id        10  non-null values
Unit_Cost_Amt         10  non-null values
Unit_Received_Cost    5  non-null values
Unnamed: 0            10  non-null values
Weight                10  non-null values
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#head-and-tail

Comment: The problem with the above is that this shows me only the column names still and tells me 5 obs.  I want to see structure output immediately, like head() in R.

Comment: I haven't used R, so I'm not sure what you mean by structure output. Calling `head` or `tail` on a dataframe will return another dataframe, so you can do all sorts of manipulation on that.

Comment: Is the output truncated is that the issue?

Comment: What do you mean "structure output immediately"?  `head` in Pandas shows you the first few rows of the DataFrame, just like in R.  Can you show an example of the output you're getting and explain what you want instead?

Comment: It shows me column names only, is it because I have too many columns? (I have 21) or the data set is too big?  Because it does NOT show me what R would.

Comment: Upgrading Pandas to >= 0.13 should fix this.

Comment: Do I need to do something special besides import pandas to get that?  It appears so given that I'm not automatically getting the updated one.

Comment: Yes, you would have to download and [install](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) newer version.  You can also change print options ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707586/python-pandas-widen-output-display))

Comment: Upgrading fixed this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Suppose you want to output the first and last 10 rows of the iris data set.

In R:

```
data(iris)
head(iris, 10)
tail(iris, 10)
```

In Python (scikit-learn required to load the iris data set):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
iris = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_iris().data)
iris.head(10)
iris.tail(10)
```

Now, as [previously answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085709/df-head-sometimes-doesnt-work-in-pandas-python), if your data frame is too large for the display you use in the terminal, a summary is output. To visualize your data in a terminal, you could either expend the terminal or reduce the number of columns to display, as follows.

```
iris.iloc[:,1:2].head(10)
```

EDIT. Changed `.ix` to `.iloc`. From [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html),

> Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.